# Recursive function in php storing results without using static

Tags: php, recursion, static

I wrote the following recursive function to keep looping through result looking for `$result->pages->next` and calling out to curl fetching the next page and aggregating the results. Finally it returns all results as a single object.

```
     private function pager($result) {
        static $all_results;

        if(isset($result->pages->next) && !empty($result->pages->next)) {
            $all_results[] = $this->get_curl_request($result->pages->next);
            $this->pager(end($all_results));
        } else {
            return $all_results;
        }
    }
```

However I really don't like using `static` and it feels poorly implemented and a source of technical debt. What is a more elegant way to do this?

**Update**

Being called with:

```
return $this->pager($this->get_curl_request("https://api/request/here"));
```

*Open to changing how it is called.*

Comment: Can you provide information on where/how `->pager()` is being called (the first call)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `$all_result` as second parameter like this and add return for this line: `$this->pager(end($all_results), $all_results);`

**Code**

```
private function pager($result, $all_results) {
    if(isset($result->pages->next) && !empty($result->pages->next)) {
        $all_results[] = $this->get_curl_request($result->pages->next);
        return $this->pager(end($all_results), $all_results);
    } else {
        return $all_results;
    }
}
```

The above code function will return the last updated array `$all_results`.

Example of use:

```
$pager_array = $this->pager($result, array());
```